# Openshift & OKD EFS Provisioner - existing directory (by defaullt pvc creates new directory in EFS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift

Is it possible via EFS provisioner to create PVC mounting to specific directory in the EFS. Current behaviour of the provisioner is that every time we use the storage class aws-efs it creates new sub directory in the EFS and pod was not able to see the existing directory in the EFS

EFS provisioner setup is inherited from this https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/storage/persistent_storage/persistent-storage-efs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by manually creating PVC and PV specifying existing EFS directory, storage class, nfs endpoint

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: efs-claim-test-directory-efs
  namespace: l2-efs-test-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: pvc-test-directory-efs
  storageClassName: aws-efs
  volumeMode: Filesystem
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc-test-directory-efs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  nfs:
    server: <EFS DNS / IP>
    path: /test-directory-efs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    namespace: l2-efs-test-pvc
    name: efs-claim-test-directory-efs
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: aws-efs
  mountOptions:
    - vers=4.1
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```